# I'm wondering why my container div is aligned to the right

Tags: css, grid

[code[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TsFo.png)

It looks like there is a margin pushing the container to the right but clearly, there is. I'm confused. Please help

My code is attached below

```css
.stat {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 3rem;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 8rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.statistic {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 8rem;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: small;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="stat">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="stat1 statistic">
      <span>86K</span> Students
    </div>
    <div class="stat2 statistic">
      <span>142</span> Tutors
    </div>
    <div class="stat3 statistic">
      <span>900</span> Courses
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please click on [1] to see a photo of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Please include a [example]. Assuming you are using React, I changed your className to class. Please add the shortest code is necessary to debug the problem, screenshots are impossible to debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
.stat{
display : flex;
justify-content : center;
align-items : center;
}
```

Use this to center your div

Comment: thanks for your help. this only reduces the container size to exactly fit the container items. really not sure why this isn't working